# Sequelize validation throwing error

Tags: database, node.js, model, sequelize.js

I'm trying to check that a username is unique, and I gather that I'd need a custom validation for that. I've written the following code, but instead of returning the error in the array returned by `.validate()`, it just throws the error, which isn't the behaviour described in the docs and isn't what I want.

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        validate: {
            isUnique: function (username) {
                User.find({ where: { username: username }})
                    .done(function (err, user) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        }

                        if (user) {
                            throw new Error('Username already in use');
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: A little o.t but is there a reason why you aren't enforcing the username by using a unique key constraint in a dbms?

Comment: Don't know how, using this library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The validation you are doing is asynchronous. You call the `User.find` method, and after that the validation method returns. Sequelize has no way of knowing that you are doing something async in your validation, unless you tell it so. Once your find call is done you throw the error, but the validation has completed, so there is no code to catch that error, which means the error is thrown and crashes the app

The way to tell sequelize that you are doing something async is to take a second argument  to your function, which is a callback. If you call the callback without any arguments, the validation succeeded, if you give it an argument, the validation failed.

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', {
username: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    validate: {
        isUnique: function (username, done) {
            User.find({ where: { username: username }})
                .done(function (err, user) {
                    if (err) {
                        done(err);
                    }

                    if (user) {
                        done(new Error('Username already in use'));
                    }

                    done();
                });
        }
    }
},
```

Could you point me to the part of the documentation that mislead you, then we can hopefully correct it :)

Comment: The documentation is fine, I was just being stupid! I'm getting a TypeError, apparently the done function doesn't exist.

Comment: What version are you on, I believe async validations are only present in 2.0

Comment: I've updated to 2.0 now, and now the validate function returns `{fct: [Function] }` and I'm not sure what to do with it.

Comment: Ah, looks like I shouldn't be calling the validate function directly now. I've got it working now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sequelize supports Promise style async operations. Specifically the Bluebird.js lib. Just change your function to specifically use the `Promise -> next()` pattern.

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', {
   username: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    validate: {
        isUnique: function (username) {
            User.find({ where: { username: username }})
                .then(function (user) {
                    if (user) {
                        throw new Error('Username already in use');
                    }
                });
        }
    }
},
```

This will also handle any errors on `User.find()` for you.
[See this example in their codebase](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/0de404640d4c71e2d1f1259356650dfb586a248b/test/integration/instance.validations.test.js#L344)

Of course the easiest way to handle unique constraints is by setting `unique: true` on the field definition itself:

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', {
  username: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    unique: true
  },
```

But this requires that you are either creating the table using Sequelize or already have a table with the unique constraint set.

Answer (score 0):

This question got a valid answer which explains how the validation option works. But in this situation you don't have to check if a user exists on your own.

Sequelizejs has a [findOrCreate()](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-usage/#findorcreate-search-for-a-specific-element-or-create-it-if-not-available) method, that checks if somethings exists before doing anything.

Very useful method :)